# Which is the best photo editing app for Symbian OS?

Tags: software, photoshop, photo-editing, smartphone, nokia

I have a Nokia 808 Pureview with 41 mega pixel sensor. It uses Symbian OS. I am looking for an app similar to Photoshop App on Lumia 720 for the Nokia 808 Pureview.

The features that I'm looking for:

- Retro comic book
- Vintage Polaroid effect
- Remove unwanted objects
- Instagram Effect
- Sunrise effect
- Watercolor photo effect

Does anyone know an app like that for Symbian OS?

Comment: At the moment, I'd say this question is on the "[bad subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)" side of things. Could you try and expand your question to explain exactly which functions you're looking for in a photo editing app?

Comment: I have added details. @Philip Kendall

Comment: This question should probably be asked on [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symbian? Have you tried [Photo Effect](http://photo-effect.en.softonic.com/symbian)?

Probably your best bet is to find a way to install Android on that smartphone :P

For Android I highly recommend Pixlr Express - which is free, simple to use, and does everything you need.

Comment: But no Android phone has 41 mega pixel camera with over sampling technique. :P @dialex